# Windows based ASCII to Hex CLI Converter

Tags: string, binary, outlook, registry, command-line-interface

I am in need of a CLI interface in which I can convert a password to binary for insertion into the registry.

I have a few hundred Outlook Express's to set up and the passwords need to be in format REG_BINARY I have them in plain text but they need to be converted so I can insert them via a .reg file. Which will be generated by a series of .bat files.

In Linux the command:

```
echo -n 'text' | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\x&/g'
```

Does the job nicely, but in windows is there any such niceness?

Preferably a CLI program or command that I can just pass a value to but if needs be I would use VBS...

Thanks!

Myles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is overdoing it, but you could install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use the exact same commands you would use in Linux.

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'll try it out

Comment: It's nice to see that you actually accepted my answer. As a final note, you may also want to take a look at [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) if you ever want some tools that Cygwin doesn't include by default (like cross-compilers).